# Specific formatting of floats and converting them to an array of chars

Tags: arduino-nano, array, float

I have an oled display which can only display 4 digits + decimal point.
I need a way to format the number into 4 significant figures;
Then I need to convert that into an array of 5 chars (4 digits and one dp) before I can display them.

Not sure how to format to correct number of digits or how to convert into a char array. I searched a bit and printf seems to be the solution(?) but I've had no luck with it so far as it spits out all sorts of errors. if you know how to make it work, please can you provide a code snippet which compiles without errors? thanks.

Comment: printf on AVR doesn't support float formatting without some tweaking in configuration files of the builder.

Answer (score 2):

Normally `sprintf()` would be the solution - however the `sprintf()` in the AVR LIBC is a cutdown version with no floating point support.

Instead you have to use [`dtostrf()`](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdlib_1ga060c998e77fb5fc0d3168b3ce8771d42.html) to get the job done:

```
dtostrf(val, 6, 4, buffer);
```

The numbers there are the maximum width of the string (note: you need to take into account any minus sign in that value), and the number of decimal places (6,4 would give you room for "0.0000" but not "-0.0000"). Make sure your buffer is bigger by one byte than your text, since you have to have the trailing NULL character in there to terminate it.

Another (nasty) way would be to go via `String` (although I would never recommend using `String` for anything, ever):

```
String s(val, 4);
const char *buf = s.c_str(); // this points to the internal char buffer.
```

Comment: Is the String class in the Arduino library reallly that bad?

Comment: Indeed it is. It uses dynamic allocation for the internal data storage, and that is a terrible idea when you only have 2k.

Comment: How about for stack-allocated String objects? Won't they get freed on return, so avoid fragmentation (Obviously unless you allocate other longer-lived objects while in the same call chain.)

Comment: @DuncanC what is a stack-allocated arduino String? It still uses realloc and free from the heap. Allocating and releasing memory is not problem, but the fragmentation is. That is also caused by changes made to a String (the reallocate can cause fragmentation).

Comment: If you define a String as a local variable in a function, or in an expression to compose Strings from other strings, those String objects should be transient (In C++ objects assigned to local variables in functions get created on the stack, and released as soon as the function returns)

Comment: @DuncanC The string object is local, but the data it allocates to do its job is on the heap.

Comment: Ok, but when the string gets destroyed, it's heap data will get freed.

Comment: @DuncanC it's not about quantity. It's about heap fragmentation. Local strings are actually worse *because* they get freed.

Comment: Well, if you are in a local function, create some objects, and then return and some of the objects persist but some don't, you have fragmentation. If you only create temporary objects and they all get freed, you don't cause fragmentation.

Comment: @DuncanC I thing you are lacking in your understanding about how the String object works. Yes, it's an object. But it's not a *simple* object. The object itself allocates memory on the heap with `malloc()` and frees it with `free()`. It also resizes it with `realloc()`. What happens to the String object during its lifetime is what causes the fragmentation - not the simple fact that the object exists. If you create a String object then delete it again then obviously you won't get fragmentation. ... cont ...

Comment: ... If you create a String object, then assign a value to it, then concatenate more data to the end of it, then get a substring, the reassign something else to it, by the end of that, who knows what your heap looks like? Strings, when used sparingly, for simple operations, can be a benefit - however the risks of using them (when you don't know *how* to use the properly, and what the dangers with them are) far out weigh the small benefit you get from them.  Every time I have seen someone with the problem "My Arduino freezes randomly" the issue has been ... cont ...

Comment: cured by removing the String objects and reimplementing it with character arrays. Every single time. Strings used by a novice are deadly. Strings used by an intermediate user are still a minefield. Strings used by a professional is something you never see.

Comment: I'm an IT professional with over 30 years of experience. It's been a long time since I worked in C++, and I have little experience with Arduino String objects, which is why I'm asking. What are the alternatives using C strings? I'm perfectly comfortable with C, but used to having printf() and sprintf(), so feel a bit lost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90282/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-majenko).